# Adding rows to RichtextBox by BackgroundWorker

Tags: multithreading, winforms, user-interface, richtextbox, backgroundworker

I want to add rows to RichTextBox which will have different colours depending on whether a row has "Error" word.

So.

I have text files(size>10 Mb) which should be shown in RichTextBox. I have a ValidationMethod which adds a word "Error" to the end of each line of a text file which is not validated. This works okay.

I have a handler of BackgroundWorker.DoWork which calls a ValidationMethod:

```
    void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {         
        e.Result = ValidationMethod(fileName);
    }
```

and ValidationMethod is:

```
    void ValidationMethod(string fileName)
    {
                //It is really huge file. So a program can be hung
                if (str.Contains("Error"))
                {
                    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
                    richTextBox1.AppendText(str + "\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    richTextBox1.AppendText(str + "\n");                        
                }
                btn_save.Visible = true;                 
    }
```

Sometimes it works okay, sometimes my program hangs. I want to highlight by Red Color rows of RichTextBox which are not validated. If I update my richtextbox by UI thread, then a program halts. So I decided to update my RichTextBox by BackgroundWorker.

How to add strings to RichTextBox by BackgroundWorker? And btn_save is not shown. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a BackgroundWorker a pratical approach to do what you want is to use the ProgressChanged event:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender,
    ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //works with the UI
}
```

in the DoWork:

```
void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {         
        var res = ValidationMethod(fileName);
        ReportProgress(...);
    }
```

use some member to exchange status. 
Another solution is to use [Control.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to call the UI modification in the UI thread.

Comment: It works okay with a small file(200 rows). But UI halts when I try to insert 80000 lines to RichTextBox. How to update UI without halting?

Comment: The result is same as all operations of UI are executed by a thread which updates UI. So my UI halts when I have big file.